# How to search with a group of keywords in Sphinx Search

Tags: php, sphinx

I am searching with Sphinx Search
Let say I want to search with "University of Technology", "How are you" these two are my
keywords. Now when I'm searching with this using Sphinx the result showing "words" list
as an array of "University", "of", "Technology", "How", "are", "you". Where I need to
perform the exact match, i.e the result word list must be "University of Technology",
"How are you" (Exactly matched results only)

Please any one suggest me what should I do with my config or query to get that desire.

Thanks :)

Comment: this search depends only for you SQL (or any other DB)  statement where the `Where` clause  should compare exactly the words you want. don't use `like` in your `Where`clause.

Comment: I am using sphinx search Library. If you do have any idea regarding this please give some valuable suggestion.

Comment: @BantyRoy you should read the manual : http://php.net/manual/en/book.sphinx.php

Comment: I guess you do not have any idea regarding Sphinx Search. Any way thanks for your interest. @Alex

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly how PHP API works, but Sphinx treat each word in a query as a separate keyword, even if they wrapped in quotes. You can check this running such query from SphinxQL client (mysql --host=your_sphinx_host --port=9306):

```
SELECT PACKEDFACTORS() FROM your_index_name_here WHERE MATCH('"University of Technology" "How are you"') LIMIT 10 OPTION RANKER=expr('1');
```

But you can notice, that tf (text frequency) of all keywords in your query must be equal 1. So all results of this query MUST contains all keywords from "University of Technology" and "How are you".

I hope this helps understand what happens under hood.

Comment: Thanks Denis Makarskiy